# How to save html data local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I save my HTML element tag data after user closed the browser. For example

```
<div class="classOne" data-random="50">
```

And i used jQuery to change the data attribute

```
$(".classOne").attr("data-random","40")
```

And if the user close out the browser and comes back the value for data-random will be 40. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can't do it.. except you recall that line of code with jQuery while loading the page

Comment: Have you tried using Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at **localStorage**?

LocalStorage allows you to store data within the browser. So even after the user close out the browser and comes back, you still have the value stored in your LocalStorage

Here is a sample code on how you can use local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("data-random", 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with:

```
localStorage.setItem("data-random","40")
```

And later load it:

```
localStorage.getItem("data-random")
```

If you want to store JSON objects, you should use `stringify()` before saving and `JSON.parse()` after loading.

Answer (score 0):

try localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
$(document).onload(function(){
    if(localStorage.rendomData){
        var data = localStorage.rendomData - 10
        localStorage.set(randomData,data)
    }
    else{
        localStorage.set(randomData,50)
    }
})
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achive it is to use cookies. Just take this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and then above the line:

```
$(".classOne").attr("data-random","40")
```

add:

```
var randValue;
if (typeof $.cookie('my-rand-value') == undefined) {

    // generate random value
    randValue = generateRandomValue //assign random value to variable
    $.cookie('my-rand-value', randValue)

}
else {
    randValue = $.cookie('my-rand-value')
}
```

at the end change static value to your variable:

```
$(".classOne").attr("data-random",randValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using cookies as well as by using local storage - 
for local storage first store first try to get value if it is stored like -

```
if(localStorage.getItem("data-random") != null){
   return localStorage.getItem("data-random");
} else {
   return 50;
}
```

and when user changes the value you can save that value by -

```
localStorage.setItem("data-random", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery function **beforeunload** and save it into **localStorage**.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('data', $(".classOne").attr("data-random"));

});
```

To Retrieve the data from storage whenever your page opens.

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('data');
```